# Azure ML webservice different datasets for learning & predicting

Tags: web-services, azure, machine-learning

I have created an experiment in Azure ML and published it as a webservice.  My dataset used for the training includes the result column, eg input columns are:

Team A
Team B
Stat 1
Stat 2
Result

When I publish it as a webservice to run new data against the model I dont know the result, so my inputs to the webservice will be:

Team A
Team B
Stat 1
Stat 2

But the webservice is expecting the columns to be the same so including result column, but as I am predicting the future I dont have any input for the result column.

How do I get the webservice to work when I dont have the result column ? (basically I need to remove the result column from the web service I think)

Cheers

Comment: If I remove the result column from the webservice columns I get the following error:

Comment: Failed
STATUS DETAILS
requestId = da94889b7cbc4c99a691468b717470a5 errorComponent=Module. taskStatusCode=400. {"Exception":{"ErrorId":"LibraryException","ErrorCode":"1000","ExceptionType":"ModuleException","Message":"Error 1000: AFx Library library exception: table: The data set being scored must contain all features used during training, missing feature(s)

Comment: If I leave the result column in & leave it with blank values the predictor predicts the same value for every game